# How to stop Music In background while using Music Services

Tags: java, android, service, intentservice

When i play the app and then close after sometimes the apps Music again starts in    background
Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

I have an activity class having Code
    @Override

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.mygame);


    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    Intent svc=new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
    startService(svc);
    // Create runnable for posting

    final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            AnimateandSlideShow();
         }
    };

    int delay = 500; // delay for 1 sec.

    int period = 6000; // repeat every 4 sec.

    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    public void run() {

         mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);}

    }, delay, period);}

   public void onClick(View v) {

    finish();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

      Intent srv=new Intent(SliderActivity.this, MusicService.class);     
    stopService(srv); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Removing Callbacks of your handler in the onStop Method in your activity class :

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    timer = null;
    mHandler= null;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: what problem are you facing ?